# Sequentially calling functions within function in R

Tags: r, list, function, lm

How can you create a function that calls some predefined functions simultaneously?

E.g. I have 3 different functions like

1. myplot(data)
2. fmodel(data)
3. mymodel <- fmodel(data)
   myconclusion(model = mymodel)

Now I want to create a new function that calls those predefined functions (from 1 to 3). What should I do?

I tried to do something like the below and receive the following error message, but I don't what was wrong.

P/s: my model involves linear regression and I've already put in the 'data' arguments.

```
myplot(mydata)
fmodel(mydata)
myconclusion(mymodel)

funlist <- list(
F1 = myplot
F2 = fmodel
mymodel <- fmodel  
F3 = myconclusion
)

callfun <- function(funrange, data, ...){
  for(i in funrange){
    funlist[[i]](...)
  }
}

callfun(1:3, data = mydata)

#Error in model.frame.default(formula = Y ~ X, data = mydata, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
#argument "data" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the 3 functions inside another function should execute them, However, depending on what the functions actually do, there may not be any *visible* output.

```
f1 <- function(mydata, mymodel){
   
   myplot(mydata)
   fmodel(mydata)
   myconclusion(mymodel)

}

f1(mydata, mymodel)
```

Again, depending on what these functions actually do will dictate the output.

**EDIT**

Here is an example for you

```
my_plot <- function(my_data){
  
   my_data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(mpg, hp))+
    geom_point()

}


my_model <- function(my_data){

  my_data %>% 
    lm(mpg ~ hp, data = .) %>% 
    summary

}


my_model_2 <- function(my_data){
  
  my_data %>% 
    lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .) %>% 
    summary
  
}


f1 <- function(my_data){

  my_plot(my_data)
  my_model(my_data)
  my_model_2(my_data)

}
```

If you call `f1(mtcars)`, all you will see is the output from `my_model_2()`, because that was the last function to be executed. `my_plot()` and `my_model()` were still executed, but you just couldn't see the results because all it does is preview a plot in the viewer, or print the model summary to the console.

One way to 'see' the plot produced by `my_plot()` is to change what it does, from previewing a plot in the viewer, to saving a copy of the plot. This may be done like this:

```
my_plot <- function(my_data){

  my_data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(mpg, hp))+
    geom_point()
  
  ggsave('my_saved_plot.png')

}
```

Or, wrapping each function inside `print` will print the model summaries to the console, and show the plot in the viewer

```
f1 <- function(my_data){
  
  print(my_plot(my_data))
  print(my_model(my_data))
  print(my_model_2(my_data))
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I actually did try to do that but only the last function was executed? Could you please help pointing out what was wrong?

Comment: My predefined functions have outputs including a plot and some texts to be printed in the console. But when I call the OVERALL function, only the text belong to the LAST predefined function was printed and there was no plot at all.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that function only prints the output of the last function? And other prior predefined functions just have no outputs at all?   
What I need is the outputs of ALL the predefined functions. I mean that's why I want to call all the predefined functions sequentially. It doesn't mean much to call many functions but only to receive the output of the last one?

Comment: Ok, updated the answer to hopefully what you are after. In some instances you might not need the output of every stage of a function printed to the console which I guess is why it doesn't do it by default. If you are planning on repeatedly executing this function (which I assume is why you want it to be functionalised), you might consider adding model output values to a dataframe rather than printing them to the console.

Comment: Yayyy, it worked like magic! Thank you so so much Hugh.